# Webform in Blank Apache Cordova project

Tags: asp.net, webforms, visual-studio-2015, phonegap-build, visual-studio-cordova

I've got Visual Studio Community 2015, to build apps for android I'm using phonegap. Is there a way to create Blank Apache cordova app( JS) where I can Add c# webforms ?

Answer (score 1):

The only way that can be accomplished is to host your web content on a server and redirect the webview to the server.  This can be tricky to accomplish since you will need to have the Cordova JavaScript files also housed in your web page.

If that is your goal, you may want to take a look at [manifold.js](http://manifoldjs.com/) which uses Cordova to create hosted mobile apps.